# "realise that I didn't do something"

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I don't why I am asking this, but is this sentence grammatically correct?

"I realised that I didn't carry my book with me".

Just wondering about the "that I didn't" phrase after "realise".

Thanks!

Comment: It is 'grammatically correct' but not idiomatic. A native speaker would say "I realised that I didn't _have_ my book with me", or possibly "wasn't carrying" or "hadn't brought."

Comment: Hmm. Right. That makes sense. Thanks, Kate!

Comment: Also, just wondering, why did you quote 'grammatically correct' ? Lol.

Comment: People often ask on this forum whether something is 'grammatically correct', but in fact a sentence can follow all the rules of grammar and yet be unnatural or even meaningless.